# Update Matrix of Individual Probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian

There are three ships (1,2 and 3) each ship is traveling towards one of three destinations (A, B and C).

Ship 1 has a 95% chance of going to A, a 2.5% chance of B and a 2.5% chance of C.
Ship 2 has a 5% chance of going to A, a 47.5% chance of B and a 47.5% chance of C.
Ship 3 has a 0% chance of going to A, a 50% chance of B and a 50% chance of C.

By taking the sum of each ships probability by region you expect one ship to arrive at each region but suppose you receive new information that two ships will arrive at A, one ship will arrive at B and no ships will arrive at C.

What is each ships probability of arriving at each region given the new information?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is each ships probability of arriving at each region given the new information?

Comment: This is not a homework site - please provide some of your thoughts/solutions.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem. The way I see it there are an infinite number of solutions that satisfy the constraints of the problem but the optimal solution is one that minimally changes the initial probabilities. So i'm not looking for a single solution as much as I am looking for a process to get to an acceptable solution. The method i'm using now allocates the change in regional probabilities over the ships then allocates the differences between the sum of each ships probability and one for each iteration. This works pretty well, but I expect there is a better way.

Comment: Solved it. This site is totally useless.